# How to install sbt plugins from source

Tags: scala, sbt

I need to get the `sbt-start-script` plugins installed, so in plugins.sbt file, I have
`addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-start-script" % "0.10.0")`, however, when I run sbt commands in the project, I get the following errors:

```
[info] Updating
[info] Resolved  dependencies
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]      com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-start-script:0.10.0 (sbtVersion=1.0, scalaVersion=2.12)
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-start-script;sbtVersion=1.0;scalaVersion=2.12:0.10.0
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/sbt/sbt-start-script_2.12_1.0/0.10.0/sbt-start-script-0.10.0.pom
[error]   not found: /Users/aucker/.ivy2/localcom.typesafe.sbt/sbt-start-script/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/0.10.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-start-script/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/0.10.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-start-script/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/0.10.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]     at lmcoursier.CoursierDependencyResolution.unresolvedWarningOrThrow(CoursierDependencyResolution.scala:258)
[error]     at lmcoursier.CoursierDependencyResolution.$anonfun$update$38(CoursierDependencyResolution.scala:227)
[error]     at scala.util.Either$LeftProjection.map(Either.scala:573)
[error]     at lmcoursier.CoursierDependencyResolution.update(CoursierDependencyResolution.scala:227)
[error]     at sbt.librarymanagement.DependencyResolution.update(DependencyResolution.scala:60)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.resolve$1(LibraryManagement.scala:59)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$12(LibraryManagement.scala:133)
[error]     at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$lastOutput$1(Tracked.scala:73)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$20(LibraryManagement.scala:146)
[error]     at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:228
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11(LibraryManagement.scala:146)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11$adapted(LibraryManagement.scala:127)
[error]     at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$inputChangedW$1(Tracked.scala:219
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.cachedUpdate(LibraryManagement.scala:160)
[error]     at sbt.Classpaths$.$anonfun$updateTask0$1(Defaults.scala:3678)
[error]     at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:49)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:62)
[error]     at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(Transform.scala:68)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:282)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:23)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:291)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:282)
[error]     at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:265)
[error]     at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:64)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
[error]     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
[error] (update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-start-script;sbtVersion=1.0;scalaVersion=2.12:0.10.0
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/sbt/sbt-start-script_2.12_1.0/0.10.0/sbt-start-script-0.10.0.pom
[error]   not found: /Users/aucker/.ivy2/localcom.typesafe.sbt/sbt-start-script/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/0.10.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-start-script/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/0.10.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-start-script/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/0.10.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? (default: r)
```

I think the `sbt-start-script` is not accessible, and I find there is still the `sbt-start-script` source code on Github, so can I install the plugin by downloading the source code? If so, how?

Comment: `sbt-start-script` is not maintained anymore and doesn't work with sbt version 1.x.x. Consider using [sbt-native-packager](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager)

Comment: I got that, thanks:)